Use of measureTime in KotlinNotebooks
I can't figure out how to use measureTime in Kotlin Notebooks.
This code from docs:
import kotlin.time.measureTime

val timeTaken = measureTime {
    Thread.sleep(100)
}
println(timeTaken)

Complains:

Line_40.jupyter.kts (1:17 - 28) This declaration needs opt-in. Its
usage must be marked with '@kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime' or
'@OptIn(kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime::class)'

I tried to add @ExperimentalTime in front of the code, but it still shows the same error.
Is there a way to use measureTime in Kotlin Notebooks?

Which version of Kotlin is the notebook using? The kotlin.time.measureTime function became stable (i.e., non-experimental) in Kotlin 1.9. If the version is older, then you'll need to add the @OptIn annotation like the error message says.

Yes, I'm on 1.8.20. Embarrassing, but I think I just didn't read the message carefully enough and didn't try the second option. Or maybe the message could've been clearer. "Try A or B" reads as "try either A or B", not as "try A, then B if A not working". But thanks for pointing to the versions too!

Both annotations typically should work, but differently. Using @ExperimentalTime will propagate the opt-in requirement whereas @OptIn does not. It's sort of like letting an exception be thrown out to the caller in contrast to catching it in the function. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html#opt-in-to-using-api for more information. That said, since @ExperimentalTime propagates the opt-in requirement, I suppose I could see it not working for notebooks, as you don't have control over the code that actually calls your own code.

Try this bro:
        @ExperimentalTime
    val timeTaken = measureTime {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        }

    @JvmStatic
    @ExperimentalTime
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println(timeTaken)
    }

OR :
  companion object {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
    val timeTaken = measureTime {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println(timeTaken)
    }
}


The main function is not needed for Kotlin Notebooks, but adding @OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class) helped, thanks!

you're welcome. If it works you can vote to it helps others
